# Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a video using OpenCV using PCA

Tags: c++, opencv, pca

I have to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors using PCA algorithm in OpenCV (c++). I'm just learning opencv so i don't know how to use PCA class in my program. I want to know where should I add PCA methods to find out the eigenvalues and eigenvector of the video.

```
    #include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

    int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
//create the cascade classifier object used for the face detection
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
//use the haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml library
face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

//setup video capture device and link it to the first capture device
VideoCapture captureDevice;
captureDevice.open(0);

//setup image files used in the capture process
Mat captureFrame;
Mat grayscaleFrame;
Mat trial;
int nEigens;
//create a window to present the results
namedWindow("outputCapture", 1);

//create a loop to capture and find faces
while (true)
{
    //capture a new image frame
    captureDevice >> captureFrame;

    //convert captured image to gray scale and equalize
    cvtColor(captureFrame, grayscaleFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(grayscaleFrame, grayscaleFrame);

    //create a vector array to store the face found
    std::vector<Rect> faces;

    //find faces and store them in the vector array
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscaleFrame, faces, 1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

    //draw a rectangle for all found faces in the vector array on the original image
    for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
        Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);

        rectangle(captureFrame, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
    }
    PCA pca(captureFrame,trial, CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, nEigens);

    Mat data(captureFrame.rows, nEigens, CV_32FC1);
    cout << nEigens;
    //print the output
    imshow("outputCapture", captureFrame);

    //pause for 33ms
    imshow("grayscaleconversion", grayscaleFrame);
    waitKey(33);

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: taking the pca of a single image does not make any sense to me. what are you trying to achieve with that ? (also, you never initialize nEigens) why is there a face-detection ?

Comment: sorry im new to opencv and pca. i just want eigenvalues and eigenvectors so that i can calculate the euclidean distance.

Comment: the euclidean distance between what ?

Comment: basically i want to extract emotion using pca.the steps are

Comment: basically i want to extract emotion using pca.the steps are video image normalisation and then grayscale conversion and obtaining eigen values and eigen vectors using pca. then finding euclidian distance between eigenvector we are going to decide emotion.